# Reference to a pointer

Tags: c++, reference, pointers

```
char *str = "Hello";

char *ptr = str;
char *&rptr = str;
```

What is the difference between ptr and rptr? I understand rptr is a reference to a pointer(in theory) but how does it differ in terms of implementation with ptr?

Are references in C++ implemented using pointers?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/difference-between-pointer-variable-and-reference-variable-in-c
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/620604/difference-between-a-pointer-and-reference-parameter
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948467/about-pointer-and-reference-syntax
and probably more...

Comment: Notice your code becomes invalid in about one year. It has been obsolete to point to string literals using `char*` for about ten years.

Comment: @Johannes - You mean the standard does not allow such string literals. Most of the books still use this notation. Where can I have a preview of such details?

Comment: @Sam: The C++ standard used to list the deprecated binding of string literals to `char*` in section D4. The C++0x FCD does not contain that entry anymore, which I guess means that the binding is no longer *deprecated* but now *illegal*, as Johannes correctly pointed out :)

Comment: The important part is that if you want to point at a string literal, use a `const char*`. That has always been and will continue to be legal.

Answer (score 17):

> What is the difference between ptr and rptr?

If you do `char *world = "World"; rptr = world;` and then print `str`, it will print "World". If you do `ptr = world;` and then print `str`, it will print "Hello".

Comment: i.e., rptr is an alias to string, ptr is a mere copy.  If you point str somewhere else, it will affect rptr, but not ptr.  In other words, you could say that str and rptr are 2 different variables (2 different names), but the same pointer.

Comment: While indeed the gist of your answer is correct, notice that you cannot do `rptr = "World"` because `"World"` is not a `char*` pointer. The implicit conversion of the char array to a char pointer won't be done here, because it's a non-const reference.

Comment: @sepp2k it's still wrong. Let me fix the code to show you what is wrong. Now you have got same situation: You have an array but you try to bind a non-const reference to a `char*` to it - it won't work. It's just like `float a = 0; int &r = a;` fails. It's easy to overlook, but just as easy to understand once you see what's up here.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: My edited code compiles in g++ with -Wall -pedantic -ansi without warning. Note that I'm not doing `char*& something = anArray;`, I'm doing `char*& something = aPointer; something = anArray;`.

Comment: @sepp2k ohh i see now. I'm sorry for being that stupid. I even tried with codepad.org before to double-check, but i totally missed that this is really just an assignment. Lemme get another cup of coffee now. Cheers!

Comment: @sepp2k: What is the significance of this statement char*& something = aPointer; something = anArray; Are you doing this because you cannot directly point a string literal (ie "Hello") using char* directly as per the standard.

Comment: @TurkhanBadalov "Hello" is stored in read-only memory (or rather writing to it causes UB, so it *can* be stored in read-only memory). `str` is either a local or global variable (depending on where the OP's code is located) and not declared `const`. So it will most definitely not be stored in read-only memory (unless the compiler can prove that the variable is never written to, which is impossible in this case because we are writing to it).

Comment: @sepp2k but if we can change str then the memory leak appears. "Hello" is located somewhere, then we change the address where str points to. We loose the address of "Hello". You mean that locating "Hello" in Rom or not is dependent on compiler? And by specification nothing is wrong with changing str? And what do you mean by OP?

Comment: @TurkhanBadalov It's not like you can `free` string literals, so the memory is "leaked" either way. Yes, it's up to the compiler to decide whether or not to store string literals in a read-only section of memory. Not all platforms even support memory protection, so it'd be a bad idea for the standard to make assumptions about that. And yes, it's perfectly legal according to the standard to assign to `str` - it's just a variable like any other.

Answer (score 12):

**str** stores the address (and therefore points) to a literal string, "Hello", which is stored somewhere in a read-only segment of memory.

**ptr** points to the same address as 'str'.

**rptr** basically points to 'str' (not to the same pointee as str, but to str itself). It might be unusual to use 'points to' for references but they're really very much like pointers themselves (in this case a pointer to a pointer) except with slight syntactical differences and the restriction that they cannot point to any other address during their lifetime.

It would be analogous to:

```
char** const rptr = &str;
```

Like a reference, rptr above cannot be assigned a new address (it cannot change what it's pointing to), but it can be free to change its pointee (which happens to be a pointer in this case to 'str').

```
*rptr = 0; // after this, str == 0
```

References are pretty much the same as a read-only pointer (not a mutable pointer to read-only pointee) only they don't require a dereferencing operator to get at the pointee (the referenced data):

```
char *str = "Hello";
char *&rptr = str;
rptr = 0; // after this, str == 0
```

The only difference from the above example with a read-only pointer to pointer is that we didn't have to use the operator*.

const references also have the unique property of being able to extend the lifetime of temporaries, but that's probably beyond the scope of the discussion.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
int main () {
    char *str1 = "Hello ";
    char *str2 = "World!";
    char *ptr = str1;
    char *&rptr = str1;
    rptr = str2;
    std::cout << ptr << str1 << std::endl;
}
```

It prints "Hello world!" because `ptr` is a char pointer pointing to the string literal "Hello ". `rptr` is a reference to a char pointer, so when you change it (the pointer, not the thing it points at.) you change `str1`. And thus `ptr` points to "Hello ". `str1` points to "World!".