# c pointers, Anyone got fundamental issues?

Tags: c, pointers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do people find difficult about C pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4025768/what-do-people-find-difficult-about-c-pointers)

New to c programming (Actually new to programming in general). Well, I just can't get familiar with c pointers. maybe, I can use them in some situations, but really am stuck to *understand* it. Anyone been in such a situation? Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to ask direct questions on Stackoverflow. But for your benefit, you would have to read some introductory book on C and then share your issues as  to which section you don't understand.

Comment: @Paul: It's close. but people there try to tell others what problems they ran into. The question author wants suggestions.so I don't think it's a duplicate.

Comment: belongs to http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ imo

Comment: @gunner Sorry, new to stackoverflow. I just feel very confused about them. Wanted to know if anyone had the same issues and what's the best way to lean them

Comment: pointers are similar to recursion - you either get it or you don't

Comment: @user I usually had to read the same book for several times to understand it, and pointers are tough. Have some patience :)

Comment: @KevinDTimm: Good Point :) . Pointers and Recursion based questions are considered the highest level of C Interview question. The hardest of most Interview questions usually compose of elements of Pointers and Recursions together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start at the [Introduction to pointers](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/67-introduction-to-pointers/). The link is to a very simple, concise, and easy to follow tutorial/e-learning site. The next chapter goes more in depth. I think you'll find the information helpful in getting a better understanding of how pointers work.

That site discusses things that can confuse people easily. Such as the following syntax differences:

```
1   int *pnPtr; // a pointer to an integer value
2   double *pdPtr; // a pointer to a double value
3    
4   int* pnPtr2; // also valid syntax
5   int * pnPtr3; // also valid syntax
```

Comment: Thank you  matt. that's a good resource.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [What do people find difficult about C pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4025768/what-do-people-find-difficult-about-c-pointers). people discussed what fundamental issues they ran into when trying to learn c pointers.

Comment: Thank you. it sound like I'm not the only one with the problem. that's a good resource.