# C++: Asterisk and Ampersnd Used Together

Tags: c++, pointers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reference to a pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3128662/reference-to-a-pointer)

I'm going through some code, and see `Foo*& bar`. How is that to be interpreted? Thanks!

Comment: Are you really too lazy to open your book? `bar` is a *reference* to *pointer* to `Foo` type.

Comment: Please tell what you have tried already so no effort is wasted.

Comment: Also see [cdecl](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=int*%26+bar%3B).

Comment: Nothing to do with laziness. Don't have a book. Googling for similar turned up nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a reference to a pointer to `Foo`. the usual use-case is when you want a function to change a pointer passed to it as an argument:

```
void foo(Foo*& bar)
{
  bar = something_else;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`bar` is a reference to a pointer to `Foo`.

Answer (score 1):

Read right to left:

```
Foo*& bar

[bar] is a [reference] to a [pointer] to a [Foo]
```

Answer (score 1):

It's usually helpful to read such declarations right-to-left:

```
Foo*& bar;
```

- `bar`
- is a reference `&`
- to a pointer `*`
- to a `Foo`

Answer (score 0):

A reference, to a pointer, to a Foo.
Probably used as a function parameter?
Possibly an "out parameter".